# How to select only cells related to a specific column from a data frame in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an interactive dashboard using shiny. I want to select only a single specific cell at any particular time related to only the first column.

When i went through https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html I was unable to find the required information. Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

This is a shiny app that shows how to do it:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)

    library(DT)
    header <- dashboardHeader()
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
            selectInput("rowNumber", "Select row number", choices = 1:NROW(mtcars)),
            selectInput("colNumber", "Select column number", choices = 1:NCOL(mtcars))
    )
    body <- dashboardBody(
            DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable")
    )

    shinyUI(fluidPage(

      # Application title
      titlePanel("Data Table"),
      dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)


    # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            output$mtcarsTable <- renderDataTable({
                    a <- 200
                    DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
                                  selection = list(target = "cell", 
                                                   selected = matrix(c(as.numeric(input$rowNumber), 
                                                                       as.numeric(input$colNumber)), 
                                                                     nrow = 1))
                                  )
    })

    })
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that if the user clicks the selected cell the selection is removed. 
A possible alternative would be to change the cell background color, but this requires a piece of javascript in the rowcallback. Let me know if you are interested to see the alternative solution.